# Espresso UI tests running when I execute single test, but fails when I execute set of tests

Tags: android, multithreading, android-testing, android-espresso

I'm using `IdlingResource` to synchronize a few network related tasks. I register and unregister idlingresource in the `@Before` and `@After` methods. The instrumentation is `AndroidJUnitRunner`.

The basic sequence of steps are:

1. Espresso clicks a button which makes a network request
2. When I get response, espresso clicks another button which starts a new activity.
3. Make more network requests via the new activity.

What actually happens though, is that the first network request is made but new activity is not started. I have a feeling that the main thread is looping somewhere, but I can't pinpoint it.

When I execute a single test (right click method, click on "Run testmethod..") it works, but when I try to execute all the test methods in the class, it fails.

The cool thing is even if every method is empty, save for one which actually does the UI testing, it still fails.

A similar question is in this thread, but has no answers: [Espresso 2 on Android, intermediately tests fail after failing to start the activity under test while activities from previous tests are still alive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34616550/espresso-2-on-android-intermediately-tests-fail-after-failing-to-start-the-acti)

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: I get the same but on a simple scrollTo object off screen

Comment: Do you still have this problem on Espresso 3?